# Apple Maps using location although not opened

Tags: ios, privacy, geolocation, instagram

After a few months I noticed that my iPhone is using my location quite frequently. This has different reasons, some of them are legit, some not so much.

In the settings you can see which apps requested your location frequently.

I did set up the location settings as following:

- **Instagram:** NO Location ACCESS
- **Weather:** Location access while using or while using widgets
- **Maps:** Location access ONLY WHILE USING
- **Find my:** Turned ON
- ...

However, I noticed recently besides **Weather** and **Find my** using my location very frequently, **Maps** is also using my location quite often just after I launched Instagram although the Maps app not being launched or running a while ago.

*Is there anything I can do about this?*

*Did some of you experience some similar behavior?*

This kind of gives me the feeling Insta is kinda using my location over a bypass or something.

Comment: the guess here is the "Find my" needs map location.

Comment: Maybe you have Maps widgets?